# Getting method from HashMap get() return

Tags: java, hashmap, processing

I am currently working in Processing 3, and am having troubles understanding the return of a HashMap. I have a map, `Map<String, Chromosome> genes = new HashMap<String, Chromosome>()` which uses my classes,

```
class Chromosome{
  Genotype geneOne;
  Genotype geneTwo;

  Chromosome(){ ... }

  Chromosome(Genotype gOne, Genotype gTwo){ ... }

  void setGeneOne(Genotype gene){ ... }

  void setGeneTwo(Genotype gene){ ... }

  Genotype getDomGene(){ ... }

  Genotype getRecGene(){ ... }
}

class Genotype{
  Object value;
  float weight;

  public Genotype(int value, float weight){ ... }

  public Genotype(int[] value, float weight){ ... }

  public Genotype(String value, float weight){ ... }

  public Genotype(float value, float weight){ ... }

  public Object getValue(){ ... }

  public float getWeight(){ ... }

  public void setValue(int value){ ... }

  public void setValue(int[] value){ ... }

  public void setValue(String value){ ... }

  public void setValue(float value){ ... }
}
```

What I'm thinking is that when I "get" a value from the map, I should be able to access its methods from there. I.E.

```
class Flower{
    Map<String, Chromosome> genes;
    Flower(){
        genes = new HashMap<String, Chromosome>();
        genes.put("color", new Chromosome(new Genotype(64, 1.0), new Genotype(25,0.5)));
        Genotype test = genes.get("color").getDomGene(); //should return the first param passed to the new chromosome
    }
}
```

I'm hoping to avoid having to declare the returned object every time I use it. From all of 20 minutes of googling, I can't seem to find anything about this working, so why does this not work, and what can be done to work around it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by "Processing 3"?

Comment: @AriaPahlavan [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a subset, I guess you could say, of Java. My question is clearly worded at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @shmosel I have updated to provided as minimal & complete of an example as I can. As for verifiable, as my question is about why something does not work, obviously it is not verifiable. I am asking why it is does not work, and what I can do about it.

Comment: Are these classes all in the same package?

Comment: @shmosel yes, they are. Processing actually compiles all classes into one file, so as far as these guys are aware, they're all sitting right next to each other.

Comment: `getDomGene()` returns a `Genotype`, not a `Chromosome`.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, that was a typo on account of being rushed. It's been corrected.

Comment: Then I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just return genOne in `getDomGene` method.

Chromosome class.

```
package gen;

class Chromosome {

    Genotype geneOne;
    Genotype geneTwo;

    Chromosome() {
        System.out.println("Chromosome.Chromosome");
    }

    Chromosome(Genotype gOne, Genotype gTwo) {
        System.out.println("Chromosome.Chromosome");
    }

    void setGeneOne(Genotype gene) {
        System.out.println("Chromosome.setGeneOne");
    }

    void setGeneTwo(Genotype gene) {
        System.out.println("Chromosome.setGeneTwo");
    }

    Genotype getDomGene() {
        System.out.println("return genOne");
        return geneOne;
    }

    Genotype getRecGene() {
        System.out.println("return genTwo");
        return geneTwo;
    }
}
```

Genotype class

```
package gen;

class Genotype {

    Object value;
    float weight;

    public Genotype(int value, float weight) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.Genotype");
    }

    public Genotype(int[] value, float weight) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.Genotype");
    }

    public Genotype(String value, float weight) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.Genotype");
    }

    public Genotype(float value, float weight) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.Genotype");
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        System.out.println("Genotype.getValue");
        return null;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.setValue");
    }

    public void setValue(float value) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.setValue");
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.setValue");
    }

    public void setValue(int[] value) {
        System.out.println("Genotype.setValue");
    }

    public float getWeight() {
        System.out.println("Genotype.getWeight");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Flower class.

```
package gen;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Flower {

    Map<String, Chromosome> genes;

    Flower() {
        genes = new HashMap<>();
        genes.put("color", new Chromosome(new Genotype(64, 1.0f), new
                Genotype(25, 0.5f)));
        Genotype test = genes.get("color")
                .getDomGene(); //should return the first param passed to the new chromosome
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Flower();
    }
}
```

It prints

```
Genotype.Genotype
Genotype.Genotype
Chromosome.Chromosome
return genOne
```

`return genOne` means that you have an access to the `geneOne` field of `Chromosome` class, that is its first parameter.

Comment: While it's not a bad idea, figuring out dominance in the constructor, this does not answer why I cannot get Chomosome's methods from the map's get method or how to work around this problem.

Comment: Actually when you call `genes.get("color").getDomGene();` it should return first parameter of Chomosome class, right? Now it is returning it. I just printed method in name to show the cycle.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Oddly enough, after simply calling `genes.get("color").getDomGene()` this morning, it just works! Must've been referring to it incorrectly as something. Marking this as the answer, due to kinda clearing things up, and getting me to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

if you put class Flower in a different package? you can't see methods that are not "public". try putting all classes in the same package or make the method public

public Genotype getDomGene(){ ... }

public Genotype getRecGene(){ ... }